# variable no definida (comision)

Tags: c#

```
double montoVendido, comision, sueldoBruto, d, sueldoNeto;
int categoria, sueldoBasico=250;

Console.Write("Ingrese su monto vendido: ");
montoVendido = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Ingrese su categoria: ");
categoria = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (categoria == 1) comision = (montoVendido * 14.25) / 100; 
else if (categoria == 2) comision = (montoVendido * 13) / 100; 
else if (categoria == 3) comision = (montoVendido * 11.75) / 100;

sueldoBruto = sueldoBasico + comision;

if (sueldoBruto > 3500) d = (sueldoBruto * 15) / 100;
else d = (sueldoBruto * 10) / 100;

sueldoNeto = sueldoBruto - d; 

Console.WriteLine($"Su sueldo basico es de {sueldoBasico} soles\nSu comision es de {comision} soles\nSu sueldo bruto es de {sueldoBruto}\nSu descuento es de {d} soles\nSu sueldo neto es de {sueldoNeto} soles");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What happens if `categoria` is not 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: It's on this line (`sueldoBruto = sueldoBasico + comision;`), right? Unless `categoria` is 1, 2 or 3, `comision` is not defined; that's what the compiler is telling you.  By the way  this is an English only site

Comment: Ask a question in English or try at https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You did not ask a question.

Comment: need `double comision = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `category` is not 1, 2, or 3 then `comision` is not defined:

```
if (categoria == 1) 
{
   comision = ; 
}
else if (categoria == 2) 
{ 
   comision = (montoVendido * 13) / 100; 
}
else if (categoria == 3) 
{  
   comision = (montoVendido * 11.75) / 100;
}
else 
{
                       <------------in this case 'comision' is not defined.
}
```

BTW. Check out [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression):

```
var comision = categoria switch 
{
   1 => (montoVendido * 14.25) / 100,
   2 => ...,
   3 => ...,
   _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(categoria), $"Not expected categoria value: {categoria}"),
}
```